# Multiple counts (over 2000 rows by 2000 columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I apologize if I can't explain myself clearly but I'll try my best.

So I need to query a table (money transactions) where in a certain, say branch R1 sends money to another branch (can be any branch (R1 - R2000)). I need to be able to get the count of transactions (money sent). The problem is that there are too many branches (2000+ branches).

The table looks like this:

[image]

This is how the results should look like this:

[image]

I did the same query with this before but there were only less than 20 branches that were considered. I did something like this.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN BranchCode = 'R1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'R1',
SUM(CASE WHEN BranchCode = 'R2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'R2',
 .....
SUM(CASE WHEN BranchCode = 'R20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'R20'
FROM MoneyTable
```

I want to know if I can be able to do this in a more efficient way.

Comment: thanks for editing! Cant attach the images before since I need more badges.

Comment: hint: use of pivoting or u could edit the question to add some more sample data & it s desired result but not in image format.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I'd like to see an answer with pivot. It's not something I know very well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without more information, such as what your table looks like, but assuming that each for each row, the value in column BranchCode indicates that a particular branch sent money, and you just want to count the number of transactions that the branch sent to any other branch the query would look something like this.

```
select sending_branch, count(*)
from moneytable
group by 1
```

Assuming you wanted transaction counts from one branch to another, then something like this.

```
select sending_branch, receiving_branch, count(*)
from moneytable
group by 1,2
```

Similarly if you wanted amounts

```
select sending_branch, receiving_branch, sum(amount)
from moneytable
group by 1,2
```

Comment: edited my question and added the simplified version of the table to queried

Comment: what do you mean by group by 1,2?

Comment: @MaryRoseVillanueva above is column order which is sending_branch, receiving_branch